# Send Notifications Push from NodeJS to React Native with OneSingnal

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

is it possible to send notifications when i insert to a mongodb database with Nodejs and send a notification to a react native app using OneSingnal? how could it be done?

I have the part of the mobile, I can already send tests from Onesingnal to my mobile but I need that when I make an insert to from Nodejs I send a notification to the mobile

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes This can be done.
from your question I can see that you are using a Node.js based API and calling it from mobile.

- Step 1 : Get the player ID 
     You can get the player ID using the event listener response of OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds); - the device details would be passed to onIds function as an argument
- Step 2 : Save it along with your user details 
     You can have a mapping to your user and playerid somewhere in your database
- Step 3 : Use the Rest API to notify users after the data entry succeeds
    The documentation for the rest api can be found here
    https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification

The above steps are required only if you want to target a user, you can directly send a notification to all using the appid and the playerid wont be required in that case.